# How to take screen shot of current webpage using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, webpage-screenshot

I was trying to take screen shot of a web page using JavaScript/JQuery. Could you please explain me the code steps I need to follow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Answer (score 15):

The [html2canvas2](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) JavaScript utility is suitable to take a screenshot of a webpage. You have to use three JavaScript libraries:

```
 1.jquery-1.10.2.min.js
 2.html2canvas.js
 3.jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js
```

Then call the function capture(), which will give you an HTML5 canvas-based screenshot in new window. It also generates a base64data value of image. It only works in browsers that support HTML5 canvas.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function capture() {
            html2canvas($('body'),{
                onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
                            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            window.open(imgString);                  
            }
        });
   </script>
```

Comment: Hi.. Can you please share the right source repo too if possible?.. I can find few while googling.

Comment: I've added a link to the library in this answer.

Comment: **Important note:**  "The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page."

Comment: where is this image saved. how can i view it?

Answer (score 0):

Here, Take screenshot of webpage using html2canvas.

**Example**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Take screenshot of webpage with html2canvas</h1>
  <div class="container" id='container'>
      <h1>Devnote is a tutorial.</h1>
  </div>
  <input type='button' id='but_screenshot' value='Take screenshot' onclick='screenshot();'><br/>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function screenshot() {
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
    }
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want real screenshot and not to convert html to image then you can try my new JS library: [screenshot.js](https://github.com/amiad/screenshot.js).

It's enable to take real screenshot.

You load the script:

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amiad/screenshot.js/master/screenshot.js"></script>
```

and take screenshot:

```js
new Screenshot({success: img => {
        // callback function
        myimage = img;
    }});
```

You can read more options in project page.