# Screen Capture for Web application

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

How to take user's current page screen shot and save into  one folder in web application,

I tried in java side, 
In that I used Robot class its taking server screen instead of client screen.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231259/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-current-webpage-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are interested in taking a sceenshot of the webpages (or parts of them), you should take a look at [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) project.

It's not taking the "actual screenshots" of the current page, but rather builds a representation of it based on the properties it reads from the DOM.

If you are using HTML5, take a look at this [Take Webpage Screenshot with HTML5 and JavaScript](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/10/webpage-screenshot-with-html5-js/)

So, this will take you a screenshot. Later you may decide what to do with it. You can push it to you server side service and store it to a file/db.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phantomjs

> http://phantomjs.org

If you want to use it along with nodejs , there are many nodejs  bridges available also

I have used node-phantom and it works really well

> https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom

Well , this is not a pure jquery solution. But i used node-phantom with the support socket.io and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for casperjs.

```
http://casperjs.org/
```

There is a nice example to capture the screen.

```
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector
```