# How to take snapshot of a datagrid directive/ table in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, snapshot

How can I take a snapshot of the datagrid directive ( an HTML5 table used in the template) in angularJS app?

Even if it can be achieved using javascript, that will not be a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by snapshot can you please explain it?

Comment: I mean screenshot of the table/datagrid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231259/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-current-webpage-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: I do not need the screenshot of the whole webpage. i require screenshot of only a certain part of my webpage which is a table. the data in table is populated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5, more specificaly with the canvas object, and javascript allow you to do just that. Not sure if you took the time to search for this topic in SO but here's an very upvoted answer to solve the problem you're describing:

[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

You'll be warned though that this will only work on a HTML5-ready browser.

Comment: Hi.. I think you must have a look at the question and comments above, once again. I mentioned that I need screenshot of **A PART OF MY WEBPAGE** which is a **TABLE (a datagrid).** There's a feature of my datagrid that the user can cature a screenshot of the data in the grid. Hope you got my point.

Comment: We use PhantomJS on the backend to generate PDF view of the pages. In this way, you can generate whatever you can show using HTML, CSS. You can generate image or pdf using PhantomJS.

Comment: And if you read the link I have provided carefuly you'll notice that it explains how you can take a screenshot of a certain part of the DOM....in your case it would be the TABLE.

You can be VERY selective about what part of your DOM you want to be rendered on the screenshot.