# How to implement a Screen Clipping Tool inside Web Browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screenshot, screen-scraping

I want to capture a part of my screen and take screen-shot of it.

[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMoGs.png)

The problem is that I need to implement this functionality in my Webpage itself. Not with the help of any extensions or softwares.

If anyone worked on similar kind of app or can provide me with some solutions, it will be helpful. Any information on 3rd party APIs for it would be helpful as well.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take screen shot of current webpage using javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231259/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-current-webpage-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: HTML2Canvas don't capture dynamic contents. I need to capture the dynamic contents as well.

Comment: Hi @AritraGanguly, the same thing I want to implement in my app. So what solution you found? I already researched and did not find the exact thing