# Take screen shot of window on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

Essentially, I have this plain HTML site - I only want to have one html file, with everything on that. On the site, there should be a button, and on-click it takes a screen shot of the page, and uploads that to /image on the domain. I tried using HTML2Canvas, but in most articles it says to download stuff and make new files etc. How do I use HTML2Canvas all on one HTML File?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--CSS:-->
<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;

}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>

<!--HTML:-->
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="capture()">Click for screenshot!</a>
<div id="mydiv">
<img class="two" src=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/786024596998909953/ubcBmeAM_400x400.jpg width="40%" height="40%">

</div>



<!--JavaScript:-->
<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
 elmnt.style.left = 20 + "px";
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>
<script>
function capture() {
    html2canvas($('body'),{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(imgString);
        }                  
    }
});
---JUST COPPIED AND PASTED the HTML2canvas code, from this site: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js

</script>


</body>
</html>



<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url(https://rfclipart.com/image/big/af-4a-f2/neighbourhood-silhouettes-of-country-houses-Download-Royalty-free-Vector-File-EPS-69644.jpg);

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 
 width: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231259/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-current-webpage-using-javascript-jquery) that explains it well, but essentially you need jQuery, HTML2Canvas (you seem to have it already) and jQuery.plugin.html2canvas.js. Here's the code you should use:

```
function capture() {
    html2canvas($('body'),{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(imgString);
        }                  
    }
});
```

Then add this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="capture()">Click for screenshot!</a>
```

This will, when you click on the button, make the `<body>` element's background (So, the page's background) into a screenshot of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the help, But I am not able to view that /image screenshot. Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean you can't view it? What's not working?

Comment: Yeah, the /image/png doesn't exist. Should i share my code?

Comment: That would be great

Comment: Just added it on the question.

Comment: The main HTML2Canvas stuff is under the second <script></script> (Sorry if the code is messy, this is my first time using HTML/CSS/JS)

Comment: @JohnSmith it looks fine maybe try it in different browsers

Comment: hummm well i might be typing the url wrong... This is the url which contains the file: file:///C:/Users/name/OneDrive/Desktop/stuff.html (stuff.html has the code), when i click on the button it changes the url to file:///C:/Users/name/OneDrive/Desktop/stuff.html#. Then I type file:///C:/Users/name/OneDrive/Desktop/stuff.html#/image/png. I still am able to view my stuff, but its not an image, and im still able to drag the image around. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: No, it looks perfectly fine. I'm lost honestly.

Comment: Okay i personally just have the code in a notepad document, and am running it from there. Are you using some software to run it?

Comment: I use Atom, with the `script` plugin.

Comment: I installed Atom, and tried it on there and it still doesn't work. Did you use the exact code I posted above, with the only change being that you added the script, on where it said so?

Comment: @JohnSmith Is the code in your question the code you're using right now?

Comment: Yes - the only difference being that i copied and pasted the script directly on where it said too. Is my code incorrect?

Comment: No, it looks fine. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: What URLs are you typing to run your code, and then to see the images. Also with the screen shot, are you sure it is a screen shot, in the screenshot the image should not be draggable.

Comment: Not sure but I just summarised the link. You may also want to do some independent research

Comment: what do you mean you summarised the link?, Can you please post the code which works for you?